# How to force cloudflare to cache api which it keeps categorizing as CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC?

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot, caching, cloudflare

I am trying to cache an api get request that produces json - using cloudflare by **page rules** : `Cache Everything` with `Edge Cache TTL > 0`.
No matter what I try - I am unable to get past: `CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC`!
Referring to the documentation of [page rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/create-page-rules) I even tried a sample xml file - but the same issue persists.

Page rule:

> https://.com:8443/cache_*
> Cache Level: Cache Everything

Using cf workers too - availed no result. The api is being served by `Spring Boot`, have tried virtually all combination of headers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read up on how to use `Cache-Control` header, as this will enable you to control the caching behavior on file types that Cloudflare would not normally cache -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cache-control

There are some cases where Cloudflare will never cache the response (for your safety) however. For example, if the server is returning a Set-Cookie response header.

Comment: Also worth looking into the newer 'CDN-Cache-Control' headers that Cloudflare (and other CDNs) recently began supporting. These allow you to specify caching behavior on CDNs, but not have it also apply to browsers / client-side - https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cdn-cache-control

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I was using an unsupported port. Apparently 8443 in NOT supported for caching.
This was pointed out by `M4rt1n` at cloudflare forum:
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/unable-to-cache-json-api-with-page-rules-stays-at-dynamic/322632/4

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427 > only port 80, 8080 & 443 supported for caching.

Cloudflare would have simply said - “8443 is not supported for caching” when i was trying to add the page rule with `cache everything`